# using sort command while strings in first column repeats

Tags: sort

I have a data file as follows;

```
ALIC 5.55 2.65 3.45
ALIC 2.56 2.78 3.99 
AMC4 3.55 3.66 4.88
AMC4 3.00 3.67 4.78
ALIC 1.00 1.00 1.00
ALIC 0.95 1.00 1.00
AMC4 0.50 1.00 1.00
AMC4 0.01 1.00 1.00
```

I need to sort these lines w.r.t strings in the first column as follows;

```
ALIC 5.55 2.65 3.45
ALIC 2.56 2.78 3.99 
ALIC 1.00 1.00 1.00
ALIC 0.95 1.00 1.00
AMC4 3.55 3.66 4.88
AMC4 3.00 3.67 4.78
AMC4 0.50 1.00 1.00
AMC4 0.01 1.00 1.00
```

But when I execute `sort -k 1 data`, I see that numeric values in the second column are sorted as ascending order. Which command produce the above sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do.

First, `sort -k 1` *starts* at key 1, but by default *stops* at the end of the line: to sort *only* on key 1, you need `-k 1,1`

Second, by default GNU `sort` performs a final "last resort" sort on the whole line - to suppress that, you need to add the `--stable` option.

So

```
$ sort --stable -k 1,1 data
ALIC 5.55 2.65 3.45
ALIC 2.56 2.78 3.99
ALIC 1.00 1.00 1.00
ALIC 0.95 1.00 1.00
AMC4 3.55 3.66 4.88
AMC4 3.00 3.67 4.78
AMC4 0.50 1.00 1.00
AMC4 0.01 1.00 1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sort by the first column in ascending order (as usual) 
and then by the second column in descending (reverse) order. 
The second column is interpreted as a number:

```
$ sort -k 1,1 -k 2nr,2 < in.txt
ALIC 5.55 2.65 3.45
ALIC 2.56 2.78 3.99
ALIC 1.00 1.00 1.00
ALIC 0.95 1.00 1.00
AMC4 3.55 3.66 4.88
AMC4 3.00 3.67 4.78
AMC4 0.50 1.00 1.00
AMC4 0.01 1.00 1.00
```

You may want to add the `--debug` flag to see exactly on which keys `sort` operates:

```
$ sort --debug -k 1,1 -k 2nr,2 < in.txt
ALIC 5.55 2.65 3.45
____
     ____
___________________
ALIC 2.56 2.78 3.99
____
     ____
___________________
ALIC 1.00 1.00 1.00
____
     ____
___________________
...
```